# Refactor polymorphism using Java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have an old code base that I need to refactor using Java 8, so I have an interface, which tells whether my current site supports the platform.

```java
public interface PlatformSupportHandler {   
  public abstract boolean isPaltformSupported(String platform);
}
```

and I have multiple classes implementing it and each class supports a different platform.

A few of the implementing classes are:

```java
@Component("bsafePlatformSupportHandler")
public class BsafePlatoformSupportHandler implements PlatformSupportHandler {

  String[] supportedPlatform = {"iPad", "Android", "iPhone"};
  Set<String> supportedPlatformSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(supportedPlatform)); 

  @Override
  public boolean isPaltformSupported(String platform) {

    return supportedPlatformSet.contains(platform);
  }

}
```

Another implementation:

```java
@Component("discountPlatformSupportHandler")
public class DiscountPlatoformSupportHandler implements PlatformSupportHandler{

  String[] supportedPlatform = {"Android", "iPhone"};
  Set<String> supportedPlatformSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(supportedPlatform)); 

  @Override
  public boolean isPaltformSupported(String platform) {

  return supportedPlatformSet.contains(platform);
  }
}
```

At runtime in my filter, I get the required bean which I want:

```java
platformSupportHandler = (PlatformSupportHandler) ApplicationContextUtil
  .getBean(subProductType + Constants.PLATFORM_SUPPORT_HANDLER_APPEND);
```

and call `isPlatformSupported` to get whether my current site supports the following platform or not.

I am new to Java 8, so is there any way I can refactor this code without creating multiple classes? As the interface only contains one method, can I somehow use lambda to refactor it?

Comment: Spring aside, sure: all you're doing is a contains check on a set. Inject the set as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick to the current design, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyGeneralPurposeSupportHandler implements PlatformSupportHandler {
   private final Set<String> supportedPlatforms;
   public MyGeneralPurposeSupportHandler(Set<String> supportedPlatforms) {
      this.supportedPlatforms = supportedPlatforms;
   } 

   public boolean isPlatformSupported(String platform) {
     return supportedPlatforms.contains(platform);
   }
}

// now in configuration:

@Configuration
class MySpringConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("discountPlatformSupportHandler") 
    public PlatformSupportHandler discountPlatformSupportHandler() {
       return new MyGeneralPurposeSupportHandler(new HashSefOf({"Android", "iPhone"})); // yeah its not a java syntax, but you get the idea
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("bsafePlatformSupportHandler") 
    public PlatformSupportHandler bsafePlatformSupportHandler() {
       return new MyGeneralPurposeSupportHandler(new HashSefOf({"Android", "iPhone", "iPad"}));
    }   

}
```

This method has an advantage of not creating class per type (discount, bsafe, etc), so this answers the question.

Going step further, what happens if there no type that was requested, currently it will fail because the bean does not exist in the application context - not a really good approach.

So you could create a map of type to the set of supported platforms, maintain the map in the configuration or something an let spring do its magic. 
You'll end up with something like this:

```
public class SupportHandler {

   private final Map<String, Set<String>> platformTypeToSuportedPlatforms;

   public SupportHandler(Map<String, Set<String>> map) {
       this.platformTypeToSupportedPlatforms = map; 
   }

   public boolean isPaltformSupported(String type) {
        Set<String> supportedPlatforms = platformTypeToSupportedPlatforms.get(type);
        if(supportedPlatforms == null) {
          return false; // or maybe throw an exception, the point is that you don't deal with spring here which is good since spring shouldn't interfere with your business code
        }
        return supportedPlatforms.contains(type);

   }
}

@Configuration 
public class MyConfiguration {

    // Configuration conf is supposed to be your own way to read configurations in the project - so you'll have to implement it somehow
    @Bean
    public SupportHandler supportHandler(Configuration conf) {
      return new SupportHandler(conf.getRequiredMap());
    }
}
```

Now if you follow this approach, adding a new supported types becomes codeless at all, you only add a configuration, by far its the best method I can offer.

Both methods however lack the java 8 features though ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following in your config class where you can create beans:

```
@Configuration 
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "discountPlatformSupportHandler")
    public PlatformSupportHandler discountPlatformSupportHandler() {
        String[] supportedPlatforms = {"Android", "iPhone"};
        return getPlatformSupportHandler(supportedPlatforms);
    }

    @Bean(name = "bsafePlatformSupportHandler")
    public PlatformSupportHandler bsafePlatformSupportHandler() {
        String[] supportedPlatforms = {"iPad", "Android", "iPhone"};
        return getPlatformSupportHandler(supportedPlatforms);
    }

    private PlatformSupportHandler getPlatformSupportHandler(String[] supportedPlatforms) {
        return platform -> Arrays.asList(supportedPlatforms).contains(platform);
    }
}
```

Also, when you want to use the bean, it is again very easy:

```
@Component
class PlatformSupport {

    // map of bean name vs bean, automatically created by Spring for you
    private final Map<String, PlatformSupportHandler> platformSupportHandlers;

    @Autowired // Constructor injection
    public PlatformSupport(Map<String, PlatformSupportHandler> platformSupportHandlers) {
        this.platformSupportHandlers = platformSupportHandlers;
    }

    public void method1(String subProductType) {
        PlatformSupportHandler platformSupportHandler = platformSupportHandlers.get(subProductType + Constants.PLATFORM_SUPPORT_HANDLER_APPEND);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

As it was written in [Mark Bramnik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835960/11733759) answer you can move this to configuration.

Suppose that it would be in yaml in that way:

```
platforms:
    bsafePlatformSupportHandler: ["iPad", "Android", "iPhone"]
    discountPlatformSupportHandler: ["Android", "iPhone"]
```

Then you can create config class to read this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {

    private Map<String, List<String>> platforms = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // getters and setters
```

You can than create handler with checking code.
Or place it in your filter like below:

```java
@Autowired
private Config config;

...

public boolean isPlatformSupported(String subProductType, String platform) {
    String key = subProductType + Constants.PLATFORM_SUPPORT_HANDLER_APPEND;
    return config.getPlatforms()
        .getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList())
        .contains(platform);
}
```